# nav-bar and carousel-caption on it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
 #slider {
     width: 100%;
 }
 .carousel-caption{
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%); 
     bottom: initial!important;
     
 }
 .carousel-caption h5{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    font-size: 42px;

 };
```

```html
<div class="carousel-item">
 <img src="images/image2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Loading">
           <div class="carousel-caption"> 
                  <h5>How To Make A Website</h5>
                </div> 
              </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUYL6.jpg)I loaded a navigation that has a slide carousel as well as a caption in the middle.
When the page is scrolled, the caption moves on the navigation by moving the page.
How can I eliminate this condition?

```css
#slider {
     width: 100%;
 }
 .carousel-caption{
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%); 
     bottom: initial!important;
     
 }
 .carousel-caption h5{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    font-size: 42px;

 };
```

Comment: Hi! Can you add some html showing the exact problem or attach some link or screenshot? The code you added is only CSS and not showing anything. :)

Comment: **this is the pic of the problem**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUYL6.jpg) .

Comment: try adding `position: relative;` to `.carousel-caption` class and let me know if that works or not.

Comment: no dude it didnt solve that ..  ):